# What's the best online tool to bulk delete tweets for free?

Tags: gratis, twitter

TweetDelete used to be a good service, but they are no longer free. Is there any good, safe, and reliable tool that allows you to bulk delete old tweets for free now? Thanks.

Comment: Since Melon Musk bought Twitter, all of them are paid because they now have to pay to access “X”’s API. Used to be that [Semiphemeral](https://semiphemeral.com) was good, but now it is gone just because of that: “But sadly, a reactionary billionaire took over my habitat (the Twitter API) and for some inexplicable reason spread toxic waste (hate speech, science denialism, crypto scams, etc.) across it at an impressive speed. It's no longer a livable environment, so unfortunately I was forced to shut down my service.”